# Validation for dropdown magento

Tags: magento-1.9, validation

My code:

```
<select class="validate-select" title="subjects" id="subjects1" name="subject" >
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__("Please select Subject");?></option>
    <option value="english"><?php echo $this->__("English");?></option>
    <option value="maths"><?php echo $this->__("Maths");?></option>
    <option value="science"><?php echo $this->__("Science");?></option>

</select>
<select class="validate-select" title="subjects" id="subjects" name="subjects" >
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__("--Please select Subject--");?></option>
    <option value="general paper"><?php echo $this->__("General Paper");?></option>
    <option value="biology"><?php echo $this->__("Biology");?></option>
    <option value="chemistry"><?php echo $this->__("Chemistry");?></option>
    <option value="physics"><?php echo $this->__("Physics");?></option>

</select>
```

Don't know why but i m not getting error message

[image]

like this message should be **display please select option** but i m not getting it how to display message

Comment: Could you add the form validation script? the above code works for me

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var newRequestTutorForm = new VarienForm('request_tutor', true);
</script> this script? another field like text,radio get error message only in dropdown not getting error msg

Comment: try the prototype validation. Validation.validate('select-field-id'). Try this to check

Comment: i try this Validation.validate('subject'); not working.and i m using so many dropdown check my update

Comment: if(Validation.validate($('subjects'))){ console.log('true')}else{console.log(false)}            Let me know what you get printed in console

Comment: false and when i refresh page that time i m getting error i want error when i click on submit button

Comment: i want error msg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]   after seeing your code i realize that you are repeating the `id` element you have same id for both the `id` must be unique so change one element `id` to `id="subjects1"`.
hope this will helps. i tested myself and it working..

```
<form id="request_tutor">
<select class="validate-select" title="subjects" id="subjects1" name="subject" >
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__("Please select Subject");?></option>
    <option value="english"><?php echo $this->__("English");?></option>
    <option value="maths"><?php echo $this->__("Maths");?></option>
    <option value="science"><?php echo $this->__("Science");?></option>

</select>
<select class="validate-select" title="subjects" id="subjects" name="subjects" >
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__("--Please select Subject--");?></option>
    <option value="general paper"><?php echo $this->__("General Paper");?></option>
    <option value="biology"><?php echo $this->__("Biology");?></option>
    <option value="chemistry"><?php echo $this->__("Chemistry");?></option>
    <option value="physics"><?php echo $this->__("Physics");?></option>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        var customForm = new VarienForm('request_tutor', true);
        //]]>
        </script>
```

Comment: i change id but not working

Comment: check it if you are not repeating on any other select because i tested it and this was problem in your code

Comment: there is no repeat id

Comment: id="subjects"   id="subjects" check both the select ids

Comment: in my code i m changing id but not working

Comment: your form name? and id

Comment: request_tutor form name

Comment: you form id must be request_tutor too add validation. because magento validation works on id

Comment: form id is also request_tutor

Comment: i posted the form. i tested it and it working on my magento 1.9.